# Multi Monitor: Why does a "Dragged For Fullscreen" window open on another monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, fullscreen

I'm a first time Ubuntu user, and I'd thought I'd give it a try. I have 3 monitors, I have them all configured to my liking and everything so I started playing around and I tried dragging my google chrome to the top of the screen so I can make it go full screen on my middle monitor.

It shows the orange box as if it's going to go fullscreen on my middle monitor, then once I release my mouse it will go full screen on my left monitor.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with videos on some servers other than YouTube jumping to the laptop screen when I switch to fullscreen on TV connected via HDMI.

I discovered that you can make them stay on TV screen by opening **System Settings... > Displays** and moving the position of TV screen there from left to top or right.

This can perhaps be helpful to you as well.